# Error en webservice PHP

Tags: php, webservice, android-asynctask

Estoy utilizando web service de la libreria SOAP para Android. Tengo este web service.

```
function ws_put_q_answers($ids, $date, $users, $completeds, $idstores, $checkins, $checkouts, $locations) 
{

    include "conn.php"; 
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ids); $i++){
        $id = $ids[$i];
        $date = $date;
        $user = $users[$i];
        $completed = $completeds[$i];
        //$noReplies = $nosReplies[$i];
        $idstore = $idstores[$i];
        $checkin = $checkins[$i];
        $checkout = $checkouts[$i];
        $location = $locations[$i];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO q_answers([id_questionnarie], [date], [user], [completed], [noReplies], [id_store], [checkin], [checkout], [location])
            VALUES (". $id .", '" . $date . "', '". $user . "', ". $completed .  ", 0, " . $idstore . ", '" . $checkin . "', '" . $checkout . "', '" . $location . "')";
        //$sql = "INSERT INTO q_answers([id_questionnarie], [date], [user], [completed], [noReplies], [id_tienda], [checkin], [checkout])
            //VALUES (". $id .", '" . $date . "', '". $user . "', ". $completed .  ", 0, " . $idstore . ", '" . $checkin . "', '" . $checkout . "')";

        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(); 

    }                                                 

    if (!$db) {
        die('ERROR.. No se logro la conexion con la BD TFBO');
        return(0);
    }  
    else {
        //$processReturn =  $val0; 
        return(1);
    }
}
```

El problema es que en ocasiones (MUY RARA VEZ en la columna de "checkout") inserta la palabra "Array" como tal.

Todos los parametros que envio son Arreglos, los recorro y guardo variables temporales.

Alguna idea de por que pasa esto en algunas ocasiones?

Answer (score 0):

La sentencia de inserción, tal como la tienes, fuerza a la conversión de los tipos de datos a string.

Si uno de los valores que estás insertando es un array (anidado dentro del array que estás recorriendo), insertará el resultado de la conversión de un array a string, que es, precisamente `Array`.

Forzar esta conversión arroja un error de tipo NOTICE. Si revisas los logs, y tienes un nivel de logueo que capture los notices, debieras ver en ellos:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in...
```

Para descartar esta conversión implícita de array a string, lo mejor sería usar la misma sentencia preparada que tienes, pero con `bindParam`

```
$sql = "insert into tabla (id, val1, val2) values (:id, :val1, :val2)";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);

$query->bindParam(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':val1', $val1, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':val2', $val2, \PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();
```

Comment: No envio arrays anidados, cada Array contiene un conjunto de Strings
Hoy realice envios de informacion a diferente hora, desde la MISMA  APLICACION y en un envio me inserto el "Array" con lo comentaba y en las demas fue todo normal. inserto valores con formato fecha '13/02/2017 16:04:27'
En caso que sea una mala conversion, Cual es la forma correcta en que deberia tener el codigo php?

Comment: Edité la respuesta para mostrar el uso de placeholders para cada variable